# prime react dropdown onchange issue

Tags: reactjs

I am using "prime react/dropdown". While dropdown, by clicking on down arrow in keyboard, it takes onChange event callback. Could any one plz help me out of this?

```
                <Dropdown
                    name="member"
                    optionLabel="name"
                    optionValue="_id"
                    value={field.value}
                    onChange={field.onChange}
                    options={assigneesList?.filter(assignees => assignees._id !== member)}
                    itemTemplate={assgineesOptionTemplate}
                    // valueTemplate={selectedAssgineesTemplate}
                    className="p-dropaassignees"
                />
```

By using above mentioned props, while dropdown, by clicking on down arrow it takes onchange event callback.

Need to prevent onChange event callback while clicking down arow for selecting in keyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't prevent the `onChange` prop itself being called but you can make it do nothing in those cases instead of calling your actual handler:

```
           <Dropdown
                    name="member"
                    optionLabel="name"
                    optionValue="_id"
                    value={field.value}
                    onChange={(e) => {
                       if (e.originalEvent.type === "keydown") return;
                       field.onChange(e)
                    }}
                    options={assigneesList?.filter(assignees => assignees._id !== member)}
                    itemTemplate={assgineesOptionTemplate}
                    // valueTemplate={selectedAssgineesTemplate}
                    className="p-dropaassignees"
                />
```